# How to perform runtime type casting in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, types, casting

I was having an error like `List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<double>` but here the problem is here `List<double>` is determined on runtime, I am doing something like this:-

```dart
extension Ext<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> deepClone() {
    List<T> res = [];
    for (var value in this) {
      if (value is List) {
        res.add(value.deepClone() as T); //List<dynamic> is not the subtype of List<double>
      } else {
        res.add(value);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Now for example, if we call this method like this:-

```
List<List<double>> values = [[3, 4], [4, 1, 2]];
List<List<double>> cloneValues = values.deepClone(); //gives an error List<dynamic> is not the subtype of List<double>
List<List<List<String>>> strValues = [[["hello"], ["world", "hi"]], [["cat"]]];
List<List<List<String>>> clonedStrValues = strValues.deepClone() //gives and error List<dynamic> is not the subtype of List<String>
```

I researched a lot and found I cannot cast it on runtime, and the problem here is I need this function for different types of lists, so I cannot create a different function for each type either, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `deepClone` is not itself a generic function, which means that it can't recursively return different types - it can only return the type defined on the extension.

Therefore, instead of making the extension generic, make `deepClone` generic:

```
extension on List {
  List<T> deepClone<T>() {
    List<T> res = [];
    for (var value in this) {
      if (value is List) {
        res.add(value.deepClone() as T);
      } else {
        res.add(value);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Also, it was probably just a typo, but in the code you posted, you iterated over `res` in your for loop, which of course will always be empty, since it was just created ;). Instead, the for loop should iterate over `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the type , and sorry but this gave me the same error

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: ```myList.deepClone<List<double>>()``` for that particular usecase

Comment: I suspect it's due to specifying the type parameter in your call. The method should always return the same type of list as it's called on - So if myList is defined as `List<List<double>>` then deepClone will already return a `List<List<double>>` without you having to manually specify it - and if you manually specify a mismatched type, then you'll see an error. If that's not the issue, then it would be helpful to edit your post to add more context

Comment: I have edited my question to provide more context, for better understanding, in your method, I was needed to manually specify the type as otherwise, the default value of T will be dynamic as it is not getting that value from anywhere else.

Comment: What version of dart are you using? When I run your code with the version of the extension that I posted, there are no errors, and the lists are cloned properly

Comment: I am using dart version 2.13.4

Comment: Ok, that's the version I'm using as well. Since it's working in my case, using exactly the example you posted with the same version of Dart, it must be that either you aren't using the version of the extension that I suggested in the answer, or there's additional context that's causing the failure

Comment: yup, u r right, I tried running your function in a separate dart file there it worked, I guess some other parameters or context in my main project which are interfering with it, Still thanks.

Comment: I found the issue, I have edited my question for it, it works with using `var` while initializing `cloneValues` but not with `List<List<double>>`